How to display content within each individual resource and each time slot in fullCalendar
I want to show a unique dynamic price in fullCalendar for each resource and each time slot.

I have used the dayCellDidMount hook but as you can see in the image below, it is displaying the price only in the first 2 rows.

Can you suggest how I should achieve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Here is the code
  dayCellDidMount: ({date,el}) => {
        const textNode = document.createElement('div');
        textNode.textContent = '10$'; // Set the text content to 'Today'
        el.innerHTML = ''; // Clear any existing content
        el.appendChild(textNode); // Append the new text node

  }


Hi. As you can see, it's quite hard to read the code when it's placed in the comments like this. Stackoverflow isn't like a standard discussion forum (see the [tour] for more info). Comments are only used for brief clarification. Your question has an [edit] button under it, which you can use to improve the main post, then the information is visible, all in one place, and can be formatted properly. To allow us to consider your code fully, please edit your question and place it there. How do I format my posts? may be useful to read as well. Thankyou.

And more generally please read [ask], and how to make a [mre] of your issue. This will help you to build a better, more useful and more answerable question. This guidance was offered to you by the system before posting anything, along with the tour - which I can see (from your empty profile) that for some reason you didn't read.

There is no hook you can use which will target a specific timeslot in a specific resource.
However you can implement your idea by using background events
For example:
eventSources: [
  {
    id: "prices",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    events: [
      {
        start: "2024-01-01 07:00",
        end: "2024-01-01 08:00",
        title: "$10",
        display: "background",
        resourceId: 1
      },
      {
        start: "2024-01-01 08:00",
        end: "2024-01-01 09:00",
        title: "$20",
        display: "background",
        resourceId: 1
      },
      {
        start: "2024-01-01 07:00",
        end: "2024-01-01 08:00",
        title: "$15",
        display: "background",
        resourceId: 2
      },
      {
        start: "2024-01-01 08:00",
        end: "2024-01-01 09:00",
        title: "$35",
        display: "background",
        resourceId: 2
      }
    ]
  }
],

Obviously this is just simple example data to prove the concept. For real usage you could apply techniques as per your situation in order to generate the list of events - e.g. auto-generating a feed from your backend for the date range fullCalendar is currently displaying, and/or making use of the recurring events functionality.
Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jORozjP
